# mysql: optimize sql query & slow query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i have big problem with my query it took more than 10 second to execute

**Many Sub Queries And Left Join**

Here is My Query

```
SELECT   tickets.tic_id,
         tickets.tic_title,
         tic_statue,
         tic_priority,
         tickets.tic_msg,
         customers.cus_name,
         employee.emp_name,
         count(comments.com_id),
         customers.cus_id ,
         (
            SELECT   comments.com_msg
            from     comments
            WHERE    tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id
            order by com_id DESC
            limit    1
          ) AS last_comment,
          (
              SELECT customers.cus_name
              from   customers INNER JOIN comments on (customers.cus_id = comments.tic_uid)
              where  comments.com_msg = last_comment
              LIMIT  1
          )AS by_customer,
          (
            SELECT employee.emp_name
            from   employee INNER JOIN comments on (employee.emp_id = comments.tic_emp)
            where  comments.com_msg = last_comment
            LIMIT  1)AS by_employee,
         tic_date,
         (SELECT   comments.com_statue
          from     comments
          WHERE    tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id
          order by com_id DESC
          limit    1)
           AS last_comment_color
FROM     tickets
         LEFT JOIN employee
           on (tickets.tic_emp = employee.emp_id)
         LEFT JOIN customers
           on (tickets.tic_cus = customers.cus_id)
         LEFT join cats
           on (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
         LEFT JOIN comments
           on (tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id)
GROUP by tickets.tic_id
ORDER BY tickets.tic_statue ASC, comments.com_time DESC
limit    50
```

Result Work Fine , But Long time

**Indexes** :
tickets.tic_id
comments.com_id
comments.tic_id
customers.cus_id

Thank you :)

Comment: Including the database schema in your question would make this probably easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a large Ticket system before with *similar* tables.  I found it ten times easier to update the main `tickets` table with a `last_comment_id` column that will let you get all that information without subselects.  Currently, you're having to scan through your `comments` table **five** times, so depending on it's size that will take awhile.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT   tickets.tic_id,
         tickets.tic_title,
         tic_statue,
         tic_priority,
         tickets.tic_msg,
         customers.cus_name,
         employee.emp_name,
         count(comments.com_id),
         customers.cus_id ,
         @cm := coalesce( last_comment.COM_MSG, 000000 ) as COM_MSG,
         @cn := coalesce( by_customer.CUS_NAME, 000000 ) as CUS_NAME,
         @be := coalesce( by_employee.EMP, 000000 ) as EMP,
         @cs := coalesce( last_comment_color.COM_STATUE, 000000 ) as COM_STATUE

        FROM
        ( select
          @cm := 0,
          @cn := 0,
          @be := 0,
          @cs := 0
        ) sqlvars,

        tickets

         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT   com_msg AS COM_MSG
            from     comments
            order by com_id DESC
            limit 1
          ) AS last_comment
          ON tickets.tic_id = last_comment.tic_id

         LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT com_msg,cus_name AS CUS_NAME
              from   customers INNER JOIN comments on (cus_id = comments.tic_uid)
              LIMIT  1
          )AS by_customer,
          ON by_customer.com_msg = last_comment

          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT com_msg,emp_name AS EMP
            from   employee INNER JOIN comments on (emp_id = comments.tic_emp)
            LIMIT  1)AS by_employee
            ON by_employee.com_msg = last_comment

         LEFT JOIN (SELECT tic_id ,com_statue AS COM_STATUE
          from     comments
          order by com_id DESC
          limit    1)
           AS last_comment_color   
         ON  tickets.tic_id = last_comment_color.tic_id


         LEFT JOIN employee
           on (tickets.tic_emp = employee.emp_id)
         LEFT JOIN customers
           on (tickets.tic_cus = customers.cus_id)
         LEFT join cats
           on (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
         LEFT JOIN comments
           on (tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id)
GROUP by tickets.tic_id
ORDER BY tickets.tic_statue ASC, comments.com_time DESC
limit    50
```

Comment: Thank you Query Master but :can you Please Explain this codes 
 **@cm := coalesce( last_comment.COM_MSG, 000000 )**

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed i just replace your subquery into left join with the help of session variable.... *@cm :=* this is session variable that variable contains temporary data and i just controller some queries data through this session varibale

Comment: You execute your query with explain then you realized your subqueries dependent on your query that the reason your query execution time is slow @MonaAbdelmajeed

Comment: **@cm := coalesce( last_comment.COM_MSG, 000000 )** look like if else

Comment: I know my query is not executed properly but i suggest you please don't use subquries .... because subquries take so much execution time @MonaAbdelmajeed

Comment: Thank You @Query Master , For Advice ,i will check your answer soon :)